# GO - How to define methods of named type?

Tags: programming-languages, methods, type-systems, pointers, go

In GO, rule is, methods can be defined only on *named type* and *pointer to named type*.

---

In C, below [code](https://github.com/shamhub/Computing/tree/master/design2Code/list), operations are defined on type(say `List`),

```
typedef struct List List; //list.h
typedef struct {

         bool(*canHandle)(ImplType);
        List*(*createList)();
        ....  
        const void*(*listGetItem)(List*, const int);
         .....
         void(*swap)(List*, int, int);
}ListHandler;


typedef struct{

  ListHandler *handler;
}ListRtti;


typedef struct List{

  ListRtti rtti; // operation on type List
  const void **array;
  /* For housekeeping - Array enhancement/shrink */
  int lastItemPosition;
  int size;
}List;
```

---

In Java, operations are defined on type(say `DList`),

```
public class DList {
  private DListNode sentinel;
  private int size;
  public void addItem(Object item){
    ...
  }
  ....
}
```

---

But in GO, [code](https://play.golang.org/p/wjB28Ijsuh) below, operations are allowed on *named type* and *pointer to named type*.

```
package main

type Cat struct {
}

func (c Cat) foo() {
   // do stuff_
}

func (c *Cat) foo() {
  // do stuff_
}

func main() {

}
```

---

**Question:**

1)

What is the idea of defining a method on a pointer to named type?

2)

How can a programmer know before hand, if `foo()` has to work as  pass by value/reference? Why GO compiler restrict defining method on both *named typed* and *pointer to named type*?

Comment: In Java you can only define methods that take a reference (roughly equivalent to a pointer), not the value itself, because classes are reference types. So Java supports the equivalent of `func(c *Cat)` but not `func(c Cat)`.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Yes, it is like opaque pointers in C. But, using references is by declaring a reference variable for a class from user code. But when we define methods in a class, we define methods for `class X`. Same holds good for C

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most OOP languages pass the current object (“invocant”) as a pointer or equivalent kind of reference. In Java and C++ the invocant is called `this`, in Python it's an explicit argument called `self`. In Java and Python this is zero-cost because their objects already are reference types. In C++, using a pointer (or reference) is necessary because that language has value semantics. If `this` were a value instead of a reference, the class defining the method could not be subclassed.

Like C++, Go has value types but it doesn't really have inheritance and can't override methods, so using a pointer is not *necessary*.

However, using a pointer is useful when:

- you want to modify the invocant, e.g. assign to a field of a struct.
- the type is large so a copy would be more expensive than using a pointer.

Conversely, using a non-pointer type for the invocant is useful if that type is very small and if you don't want to modify that object. In general, you'd use a non-pointer invocant for “primitive” types since they are fairly small. This should be treated as a micro-optimization; in most cases you do want a pointer for user-defined types.

Comment: So as per GO syntax(above), `Cat c` is non-reference type unlike java

Comment: @overexchange exactly. As in C, structs are value types. You can see the difference by adding a `name` field to `Cat`, and creating a method `func (c Cat) rename(newName string) { c.name = newName }` – this method won't do anything, unless you change it to accept a `*Cat` instead.

Comment: **1)** In GO, as implicit(`this`, `self`), not getting passed, I would need explicit mentioning of receiver type(`c *Cat`) in the operation(`reName`) unlike Java and C++, which explains usage of *pointer to named type*.Understood. My first question is answered. **2)** Any idea on second question. why do I get `method:redeclared error`? Why GO allow either but not both?

Comment: @overexchange Because Go let's you invoke pointer-methods on values, i.e. `object.method()` may be a shortcut for `(&object).method()`. To avoid ambiguity between those cases, you can't declare the same method for a pointer and non-pointer type.

Comment: **1)** I see the call resolutions, but, implicitly `func foo(c *Cat){..}` is not same as `func (c Cat) foo(c Cat){..}`. So, there is no function overloading. **2)** Programmer should take a call, whether to define pointer method or non-pointer method. Obviously, pointer method is better efficient for small/big objects.

Comment: So,Can I say, GO did not allow both pointer & non-pointer method, because it is not required? so it is recommended to use pointer method?

Comment: @overexchange Yes, for user defined types pointer methods should be preferred. While directly invoking a method may implicitly use pointer methods, interfaces see pointer and value types separately. If a type `T` tries to implement `interface { a(); b() }` then the methods `a`, `b` must both be defined on either a `T` or a `*T` receiver – the methods `func (t T) a(){…} func (t *T) b(){…}` do not satisfy that interface since `T` and `*T` is a different type. Because a pointer receiver is sometimes required, this effectively means it should be used always.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52742/discussion-between-overexchange-and-amon).

Comment: @overexchange Reading the excellent answer to your question there, my above explanation seems to be slightly incorrect. That answer states that the compiler declares a corresponding `func (c *Cat) …` method for every `func (c Cat) …` method. This indicates that instead of declaring all methods with pointer receiver, one should use pointer values when casting an object to an interface. But your other question covers this better.

Comment: Can we discuss [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52742/discussion-between-overexchange-and-amon)? we are deviating from question. You can delete your previous comment

Comment: @overexchange sorry, I don't have the time for an extended chat.